# gradle multi-project layout

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to gradle and am trying to create a directory layout as such:

```
myproject
    |-- gradle // contains the gradle wrapper jars
|-- ear
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- ...
|-- core
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- ...
|-- web
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- ...
    |-- gradlew.bat
|-- settings.gradle // has include "ear", "core", "web"
```

1. do I need a build.gradle in the root (myproject) directory?
2. how do I refer to the web project from the ear project as a deployment file?

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html,  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read [this page](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) and have determined the following:

> A Build script (`build.gradle`) **is not** required in the root if it is a multi module project. However, a `settings.gradle` file must be located in the root to inform gradle(w) what projects will be participating in the build.

if more information becomes relevant i will let you know.

Also, the projects are referred to by the name defined in the settings.gradle file

see [reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)